# c++ vector of struct init

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I am new to C++ and I am trying to initialize a vector of struct as code below.

```
struct Node{
int x;
Node *p;
int rank;
Node(int x) {
    this->p = this;
    this->x = x;

    this->rank = 0;
}
};

int main() {
   vector<Node> disjointSets;
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
     Node a(i);
     disjointSets.push_back(a);
   }
}
```

In main, I try to create a Node a each time and push it into vector. But I later find there is an issue that a is always created at the exact same memory location. Therefore, the p, which is supposed to point to each Node itself will point to the last element after the loop. May someone explain why Node a is always created at same memory address and how to solve the issue?

Comment: It makes me curious to find what is happening in the push_back operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior, because you haven't defined a custom copy constructor for your `Node` class.

`disjointSet.push_back(a);` makes a copy of `a`. This is using the default copy constructor, which simply does an element-wise copy of all the member variables. So in the copy, `p` points to the address of the original `Node`, not itself. But that `Node` is destroyed when the loop iteration ends, so the pointer is no longer valid. It's implementation-dependent, but pretty common that the loop happens to use the same stack memory for `a` each time through the loop, so `p` in all the elements points to that same address, which is no longer a valid `Node`.

You need to define a copy constructor that sets `p` to the address of the copy:

```
Node(const Node &oldnode) {
    p = this;
    x = oldnode.x;
    rank = oldnode.rank;
}
```

and a copy assignment operator:

```
Node& operator=(const Node &oldnode) {
    if (&oldnode != this) {
        x = oldnode.x;
        rank = oldnode.rank;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: You should also implement a copy assignment operator, whose compiler-generated implementation also suffers from the same member-wise copy issue as the compiler-generated copy constructor, and so will set `p` incorrectly if not overridden: `Node& Node::operator=(const Node &rhs) { if (&rhs != this) { x = rhs.x; rank = rhs.rank; } return *this; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, added that using the idiom from another question.

Comment: unless you implement your own `swap` overload that ignores `p`, the generic `swap` will make a copy of `p` that you don't want in this situation. Either `swap` the `x` and `rank` members individually, or don't use `swap` at all

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right, the generic method doesn't work for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using heap memory. Storing the address of a local variable and trying to access it elsewhere is UB. If I'm correct, The answer for "why" the same memory space is taken for each iteration of the loop is implementation defined and in this case, it is reusing the same stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Your node's are created on the stack. And address which is assigned inside the constructor points to the stack. If you want the `Node`s a constant address which doesn't change while they are moved/copied into the container you need to heap allocate them and use a vector of Node pointers. E.g. a `vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>`.